# How to customize list-group-item colors in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3, I have customized a  list group like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-mine"href="/path"><strong>Item 1</strong></a>
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-mine"href="/path"><strong>Item 2</strong></a>   
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-mine"href="/path"><strong>Item 3</strong></a>                   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-group-item-mine {
  background-color: #f1f9fb;
  border-top: 1px solid #0091b5;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-right-color: #fff;
}

.list-group-item-mine a:hover {
  background-color: red;

}
```

The problem is that when hovered on, the list-group items are still turn gray as per default, while I need them to become red. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use your custom class in parent `.list-group-mine` rather than on child...it will give you better control to style the inner elements

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.list-group-mine .list-group-item {
  background-color: #f1f9fb;
  border-top: 1px solid #0091b5;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-right-color: #fff;
}

.list-group-mine .list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="list-group list-group-mine">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/path"><strong>Item 1</strong></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/path"><strong>Item 2</strong></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/path"><strong>Item 3</strong></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
a.list-group-item:hover{
background:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/6b4zzqab/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change `.list-group-item-mine a:hover {` to `.list-group-item-mine:hover {`

The *a* element is not a child of the *list-group-item-mine* class therefore the class was not applying.

Comment: Then you will also need to apply the !important flag after background-color